# Jsoup Delay due to Streaming Website

Tags: html, browser, jsoup

A question regarding Jsoup: I am building a tool that fetches prices from a website. However, this website has streaming content. If I browse manually, I see the prices of 20 mins ago and have to wait about 3 secs to get the current price. Is there any way I can make some kind of delay in Jsoup to be able to obtain the prices in the streaming section? I am using this code:

```
conn = Jsoup.connect(link).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/28.0.1500.72 Safari/537.36");

conn.timeout(5000);

doc = conn.get();
```

Comment: And the method you've posted does not work..?

Comment: Thanks! It will fill the document but only with delayed prices. The problem is that I need the prices that the website displays like 3 seconds after you initially load the page.

Comment: The prices are really coming in the same HTTP connection? Or it is loaded by some JS code in the page? Could you show us a part of that stream, just to understand better?

Comment: If the prices are automatically updated using javascript, Jsoup cannot fetch them, unless you add a javascript parser and interpreter to it.

Comment: ...HtmlUnit will give you JS.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments, the site is most likely using some type of scripting that just won't work with Jsoup.  Since Jsoup just get the initial HTML response and does not execute any javascript.

I wanted to give you some more guidence though on where to go now.   The best bet, in these cases, is to move to another platform for these types of sites.   You can migrate to [HTMLUnit](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/) which is a headless browser, or [Selenium](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/) which can use HTMLUnit or a real browser like Firefox or Chrome.  I would recommend Selenium if you think you will ever need to move past HTMLUnit as HTMLUnit can sometimes be less stable a browser compared to consumer browsers Selenium can support.  You can use Selenium with the HTMLUnit driver giving you the option to move to another browser seamlessly later.

Answer (score 1):

You can Use a JavaFX [WebView](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/WebViewSample.java.htm) with javascript enabled. After waiting the two seconds, you can extract the contents and pass them to JSoup.

```
(After loading your url into your WebView using the example above)
String text=view.getEngine() executeScript("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```